# Android L -- Play Ripple Effect on View

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design, rippledrawable

I am trying to play a ripple effect (from Android L) on a view at a certain time (not on the view being touched).
To be specific, when the user successfully changes some text, I want a certain view to play a green ripple effect to show success.  Is there any way to do this?

I have tried putting a RippleDrawable in an Animation, putting the RippleDrawable as the background for my "success view."  But, I can't figure out how to play the ripple animation as I have described.

P.S. My project is Android L only right now, so I am not worried about backwards compatibility.

Comment: just guessing: (from the docs) `The default touch feedback animations for buttons use the new RippleDrawable class, which transitions between different states with a ripple effect.` so probably you want to call `setState` or something similar on the Drawable to trigger the effect.

Comment: @Budius Thank you.  Sadly, int[] state = new int[] {android.R.attr.state_focused, android.R.attr.state_pressed}; view.getBackground().setState(state); didn't work.  That was a great thought, though.  Am I doing that right, btw?

Comment: How is your ripple defined?

Comment: @alanv http://pastebin.com/cKU5RpLP

Answer (score 2):

Since your mask is just a solid rectangle, you can simplify your ripple XML to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask" android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/file_item_selector"/>
</ripple>
```

You can manually trigger a ripple effect by forcing a view in and out of the pressed state.

```
myView.setPressed(true);

// For a quick ripple, you can immediately set false.
myView.setPressed(false);

// Or for a long ripple, you can post to a handler.
myView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        myView.setPressed(false);
    }
}, 500 /* delay in milliseconds */);
```

Comment: Bah, no luck.  That didn't produce the ripple.  Thanks for the idea, though.

Comment: Does the ripple show up when you touch the view? There might be a problem somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, the ripple shows up fine when I am touching the view.

Comment: Weird, this might be a bug in L preview -- would you be able to zip up a minimal project that reproduces the issue so I can check against our development branch?