# How to trigger ripple effect on Android Lollipop, in specific location within the view, without triggering touches events?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, rippledrawable

This is a short question:

Suppose I have a `View` with the `RippleDrawable` as background.

Is there an easy way to trigger the ripple from a specific position without triggering any touch or click events?

Answer (score 35):

Yes there is! In order to trigger a ripple programatically you have to set the state of the `RippleDrawable` with `setState()`. Calling `setVisible()` does **NOT** work!

---

## The Solution

To show the ripple you have to set the state to pressed and enabled at the same time:

```
rippleDrawable.setState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed, android.R.attr.state_enabled });
```

The ripple will be shown as long as those states are set. When you want to hide the ripple again set the state to an empty `int[]`:

```
rippleDrawable.setState(new int[] {  });
```

You can set the point from which the ripple emanates by calling `setHotspot()`.

---

## How it works

I have debugged a lot and studied the source code of `RippleDrawable` up and down until I realised that the ripple is actually triggered in `onStateChange()`. Calling `setVisible()` has no effect and never causes any ripple to actually appear.

The relevant part of the source code of `RippleDrawable` is this:

```
@Override
protected boolean onStateChange(int[] stateSet) {
    final boolean changed = super.onStateChange(stateSet);

    boolean enabled = false;
    boolean pressed = false;
    boolean focused = false;

    for (int state : stateSet) {
        if (state == R.attr.state_enabled) {
            enabled = true;
        }
        if (state == R.attr.state_focused) {
            focused = true;
        }
        if (state == R.attr.state_pressed) {
            pressed = true;
        }
    }

    setRippleActive(enabled && pressed);
    setBackgroundActive(focused || (enabled && pressed));

    return changed;
}
```

As you can see if both the enabled and pressed attribute are set then both the ripple and background will be activated and the ripple will be displayed. 
Additionally as long as you set the focused state the background will be activated as well. With this you can trigger the ripple and have the background change color independently.

If you are interested you can view the entire source code of `RippleDrawable` [**here**](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.1_r1/android/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable.java#RippleDrawable.onStateChange%28int%5B%5D%29).

Comment: Say, suppose I have a view that I've handled `OnTouchListener` on it to handle dragging, and I've identified clicking by using `GestureDetectorCompat` with `onSingleTapUp` being called on its `GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener`. For some reason using any of the solutions here to trigger the ripple effect didn't work, and I tried it even as a foreground instead of background, meaning `android:foreground="?attr/actionBarItemBackground"` on the parent view (FrameLayout) . Any idea why, and how I can do it?

Comment: @androiddeveloper 
I don't have your scenario exactly but I had an onTouch where I wanted to trigger rippleDrawable. Calling rippleDrawable.setState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed, android.R.attr.state_enabled }); on ACTION_DOWN and calling rippleDrawable.setState(new int[] {  }); on ACTION_UP worked. 

Also, a possibility is the ripple drawable you're using isn't using the default states and needs a different set of states to trigger it.

Comment: Sadly it was a long time ago that I asked this. Sorry and thank you. If I go back to such a case again I might check it out again

Answer (score 24):

I incorporated/combined the answers from @Xaver Kapeller and  @Nikola Despotoski above:

```
protected void forceRippleAnimation(View view)
{
    Drawable background = view.getBackground();

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21 && background instanceof RippleDrawable)
    {
        final RippleDrawable rippleDrawable = (RippleDrawable) background;

        rippleDrawable.setState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed, android.R.attr.state_enabled});

        Handler handler = new Handler();

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override public void run()
            {
                rippleDrawable.setState(new int[]{});
            }
        }, 200);
    }
}
```

To programmatically force a ripple effect on command, simply call forceRippleAnimation(), passing the View you want to ripple as a parameter.

Comment: change to if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21 && background instanceof RippleDrawable), because of crash on android < 21

Comment: @iscariot. Good call.  Just changed it.

Comment: To reset state to current values call `rippleDrawable.setState(view.getDrawableState())` instead of forcing empty state set.

Answer (score 18):

Here is combination of Nikola's setHotSpot() and https://stackoverflow.com/a/25415471/1474113

```
private void forceRipple(View view, int x, int y) {
    Drawable background = view.getBackground();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP && background instanceof RippleDrawable) {
        background.setHotspot(x, y);
    }
    view.setPressed(true);
    // For a quick ripple, you can immediately set false.
    view.setPressed(false);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

First, you need to get the drawable from the View.

```
private void forceRippleAnimation(View v, float x, float y){
   Drawable background = v.getBackground();
   if(background instanceof RippleDrawable){
     RippleDrawable ripple = (RippleDrawable)background;
     ripple.setHotspot(x, y);
     ripple.setVisible (true, true);
   }

}
```

Method `setHotspot(x,y);` is used to set from where the ripple animation will start, otherwise if not set, the `RippleDrawable` will take the `Rect` where it resides (i.e the `Rect` of the View where it is set as background) and will start the ripple effect from the center.

`setVisible(true, true)` will make the drawable visible and last argument will force animation regardless of the current drawable state.

Comment: Nice. Does the animation work like a click, or a long click (meaning the selection will stay) ?

Comment: You should try setting drawable state programmatically. Like:
`int[] state = new int[]{ android.R.attr.state_pressed }` and `ripple.setState(state);`. I haven't tested if you should couple it with `setVisible(true,true)`. Because the drawable is automatically updated/animated upon state changes.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you please post a sample for both behaviors?

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski Calling `setVisible()` does not actually trigger a ripple. Turns out you don't need to call `setVisible()` at all. You just have to set the state to both pressed and enabled. See my answer for more details!

Answer (score 2):

I used the following Kotlin variant of Luke's code to manually show and hide a ripple when swiping cells out of a RecyclerView:

```
fun View.showRipple() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21 && background is RippleDrawable) {
        background.state = intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_pressed, android.R.attr.state_enabled)
    }
}

fun View.hideRipple() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21 && background is RippleDrawable) {
        background.state = intArrayOf()
    }
}
```

Comment: I love this. Thank you. I added a `View.ripple()` function too to make it even easier: 
```fun View.ripple(scope: CoroutineScope) { showRipple(); scope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) { delay(200); hideRipple() } }```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys! Your answers help with my problem, but I had to build a solution from multiple answers.

My problem was with transparent `RecyclerView` item (header) and buttons behind it. You may see this situation on picture:

[image: How application looks]

For click on **followers/liked/subscriptions** buttons I had to add `View.OnTouchListener` for `RecyclerView` header:

```
class ProfileHeaderHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    private val clickView: View = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_header_view)

    fun bind(callback: View.OnTouchListener) {
        clickView.setOnTouchListener(callback)
    }

    fun unbind() {
        clickView.setOnTouchListener(null)
    }
}
```

And inside `Fragment` simulate button click and ripple effect:

```
/**
 * [View.performClick] should call inside [onTouch].
 */
override fun onTouch(view: View?, ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
    if (ev == null) return true

    val followersContainer = followersContainer ?: return true
    val likeContainer = likeContainer ?: return true
    val subscriptionsContainer = subscriptionsContainer ?: return true
    
    when {
        ev.onView(followersContainer) -> if (followersContainer.isClick(ev)) {
            followersContainer.performClick()
        }
        ev.onView(likeContainer) -> if (likeContainer.isClick(ev)) {
            likeContainer.performClick()
        }
        ev.onView(subscriptionsContainer) -> if (subscriptionsContainer.isClick(ev)) {
            subscriptionsContainer.performClick()
        }
    }

    return true
}

/**
 * [MotionEvent.ACTION_UP] - user make click (remove ripple)
 * [MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN] - user start click (show ripple)
 * [MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL] - user move touch outside of [View] (remove ripple)
 */
private fun View.isClick(ev: MotionEvent): Boolean {        
    when (ev.action) {
        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
            changeRippleState(ev, isTouch = false)
            return true
        }
        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> changeRippleState(ev, isTouch = true)
        MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL -> changeRippleState(ev, isTouch = false)
    }
    
    return false
}

/**
 * [this] show have android:background with ripple drawable (?attr/selectableItemBackground).
 */
private fun View.changeRippleState(ev: MotionEvent, isTouch: Boolean) {
    val rippleDrawable = background as? RippleDrawable ?: return

    /**
     * For emulate click position.
     */
    rippleDrawable.setHotspot(ev.rawX, ev.rawY)
    isPressed = isTouch
}
```

I check another way to set press state for `RippleDrawable` and it's also works:

```
rippleDrawable.state = if (isTouch) {
    intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_pressed, android.R.attr.state_enabled)
} else {
    intArrayOf()
}
```

Extension for check `MotionEvent` happen inside `View` or outside:

```
fun MotionEvent?.onView(view: View?): Boolean {
    if (view == null || this == null) return false

    return Rect().apply {
        view.getGlobalVisibleRect(this)
    }.contains(rawX.toInt(), rawY.toInt())
}
```