# Adding Onclick animation to spanned sections of spannablestringbuilder

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-styles, spannablestringbuilder

I have successfully implemented the `SpannableStringBuilder` such that sections are colored differently and are click-able. However I need to include some onclick animation for a better user experience. How can I implement this. I have done a lot of unsuccessful research and methods.

Here is a pseudo-code I use:

```
ForegroundColorSpan span = new ForegroundColorSpan(color);
spannablestringBuilder.setSpan(span, 0, 5, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
spannablestringBuilder.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f), 0, 5, 0);

textView.setText(stringBuilder);
```

Comment: How about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27235843/5015207)?

Comment: That is really a good way to go, but RippleDrawable is not compatible in API 16, I've tried implementing but getting the error related with the API